# Fullcalendar - can't change background color of calendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I try to change a background-color of fullcalendar.

I tried these methods (without success):

```
td .fc-unthemed td.fc-today {
 background: red !important;
}

.fc-unthemed td.fc-today > tr > td{
 background: blue !important;
}

.fc-unthemed td.fc-today td{
 background: black !important;
}

.fc-unthemed td.fc-today {
 background: green !important;
 background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(204, 204, 204, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.fc td {
 background-color: #333 !important;
}

.fc th {
  background-color: #333 !important;
}
```

My dependencies:
"@angular/core": "~9.0.5", "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.5-beta", "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.0",

[image]

Update:
I tried with add class to fullCalendar (without success)

```
<full-calendar
  #specCalendar
  ...
  [className]="'spectator-calendar'"
  >
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a theme? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theming . It probably wouldn't be too hard to adapt an existing theme to your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try css changes in general style.css. You can't change it, if you write in component.css.

if you have more then on calendar then add class to your calendar 
add class    `<full-calendar class="testClass "`
Write these codes in your style.css

```
    .testClass .fc-view-container {
    background: #ffffff57  !important
}
.testClass .fc-unthemed th, .fc-unthemed td, .fc-unthemed thead, .fc-unthemed tbody, .fc-unthemed .fc-divider, .fc-unthemed .fc-row, .fc-unthemed .fc-content, .fc-unthemed .fc-popover, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-view, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {
    border-color: #949494;
}
.testClass  .fc-time-grid .fc-slats {
   background:#333 !important;
   color:white;
}
```

Comment: I'm using FullCalendar components in a few places. The view of the calendar is different depending on the compoennt. Previously I was able to set css style for any calendar in compoennt style.

Comment: then add class to your calendar element tag and in style css change this class style

Comment: So, I changed fullcalendar class. I changed scss (in global style.scss) and all is working expect background-color (.fc td). Here is my code:
```
 .testClass {
  .fc-view-container {
    background: #ffffff57 !important //working
  }

  .fc-unthemed th, .fc-unthemed td, .fc-unthemed thead, .fc-unthemed tbody, .fc-unthemed .fc-divider, .fc-unthemed .fc-row, .fc-unthemed .fc-content, .fc-unthemed .fc-popover, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-view, .fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {
    border-color: #949494; //worikng
  }

  .fc td {
    background-color: #333 !important; //notworking
  }
}``

Comment: I edited answer such like that. Put class to element tag and in style css put . test in frond of styles. Then u make uniqe every calendar with class

Comment: Your code is full working, but doesn't change a background color. To change bg color i can use   .fc td { background-color: #333 !important; } and this is working without .testClass. When I add this inside a testClass that not work.

Comment: u should look at its full css path from developer console, then  add your class name in frond of its path and chanage style in style.css

Comment: I updated question. There is a image from my console. Can you explain me what I'm doing woring with css path?

Comment: the write to css .testClass .fc-unthemed td.fc-today{ background-color: #333 !important; }

Comment: I tried exactly as you wrote, not working :( When I remove .testClass from css it work's

Comment: Updated question -> add html code with fullCalendar class name

Comment: Can u see what u wrote in developer console after u wrote it. U need to see it

Comment: If u create stackblitz example . Then we can easily solve it

Comment: Can u try this         `.testClass  .fc-time-grid .fc-slats {
   background:#333 !important;
   color:white;
}`

Comment: your last commnet also not woriking. I prepare stackblitz env: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccwg5y
Please change yellow background for today color.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usy1mr I changed today color to  #333